# How to read raw data sent to a port (python)

Tags: python, sockets, port, packet-capture

I just want to intercept raw data (hex)--headers and all--sent to a port, and relay them over an xmpp server. Then I would like to be able to replay to the port with hex I receive in a similar manner.

I tried raw sockets, as described [here](http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=11513), and got the same error. I am not sure how to use pcap (the one for python) to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [pylibpcap](http://pylibpcap.cvs.sourceforge.net)? Looking at an [example](http://pylibpcap.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pylibpcap/pylibpcap/examples/sniff.py?revision=1.5&view=markup) it looks pretty straight-forward to use.

Comment: Your right, given the example, that does seem like it would do the trick. Thanks.